# How can I see whether a user deletion was voluntary or forced?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I've noticed that one user / account was removed. How can I see whether a user deletion was voluntary (i.e., requested by the user) or forced?

Comment: You cannot. Why would you want to? Curiosity?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355329/be-more-proactive-when-a-user-continuously-downvotes-another-user

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ user* is correct, i.e. trying to understand the serial/targeted downvote detection mechanism.

Comment: You have no right to this information.

Comment: Moderator's aren't allowed to share it, best you can hope for is for the deleted user to provide that information.

Comment: @BryanKrause Why? Many websites/services display when a user gets banned.

Comment: @user400654 got it, thanks.  You're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Franck Deletion is not a "ban" in the way suspension is. Suspensions are displayed (but not promoted). Deletions are not.

Comment: @BryanKrause ok. Many websites/services also display when a user gets terminated.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I hope Stack isn't going around terminating users... Their accounts, maybe.

Comment: @JonCuster I don't know, I've never read SE's ToS.

Comment: I personally delete about a spammer or 2 every day. We don't really unilaterally delete accounts other than spammers or socks.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks, can the serial/targeted downvote detection mechanism give account suspension or deletion automatically?

Comment: No. They won't. Both needs a mod to notice and manually do the deed. Account deletions and mergers are a bit too messy to fix if done in error to be automated I suspect

Comment: What good would come from this knowledge about this user’s profile be to the community?  The profile deletion was handled the way it was handled for a reason.  The moderator who took that action, and the rest of their moderator team, are aware of that reason.  The proper action was taken.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not what this question is about: I'm simply asking whether one can see whether a user deletion was voluntary or forced. No intent to start a debate.

Comment: You are not privy to every moderator action against another user’s profile.  When a user is suspended you are given a generic reason for the reason.  It’s never been the policy to go into the details of every moderator action against another user.

Comment: @Ramhound sounds like an answer and not a comment. Happy to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't.

Obviously the moderator, or other user with some authority, who deleted the user can tell you...but I doubt that they're allowed to share that information.  The best way to get that info would be to ask the deleted user, but since they'll no longer have an account, you'll have to get in touch with them another way.