# Are moderators allowed by the Stack Exchange anti-serial-downvote script to serial downvote more than regular users?

Tags: support, down-votes, moderators, serial-voting

I got serial downvoted by a moderator on the [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com):

[image]

To my surprise, the downvotes didn't get reversed by the Stack Exchange anti-serial-downvote script. My prior experience with getting serial downvoted is that if a user cast four or more  downvotes on my questions, then it'll get reversed within 24 hours.

For example, when a normal user serially downvoted me:

[image]

It got reversed a few hours afterward (and then when the same user serial downvoted the next day with only 2 downvotes, it didn't get reversed since it was below the threshold to trigger the Stack Exchange anti-serial-downvote script).

Are moderators allowed by the Stack Exchange anti-serial-downvote script to serial downvote more than the regular users?

---

Note: I'm not here to discuss the reasons of the downvotes but only the Stack Exchange anti-serial-downvote script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are moderators allowed by the Stack Exchange anti-serial-downvote script to serial downvote more than the regular users?

## [No.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGpW0.gif)

First, let's look at an [answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9061/273449) to the question [Serial voting by a moderator](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9059/serial-up-and-down-voting-by-a-moderator) on Physics Meta:

> Voting by moderators works exactly the same way it works for other users, and moderators are subject to the same voting restrictions as other users.  The serial voting detection and reversal mechanism is an automatic system process (no human intervention) and it works the same on moderators as it does on unprivileged users.

Second, I doubt they would give you any details about the script, for security reasons.