# Is 7 Socratic badges the current per-site record?

Tags: discussion, badges, statistics, asking-days-badges

I'm a big fan of the [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) because in my experience, asking 100 upvoted questions on separate days is hard: it requires long-term and consistent dedication, and you learn a substantial amount along the way.

I noticed (via [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676755/top-most-socratic-users-and-their-socratism)) the users [mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic?userid=65387) and [Cheok Yan Cheng](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic?userid=72437) have 7 Socratic badges at Stack Overflow, and [0xbadf00d](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/409/socratic?userid=47771) has 7 Socratic badges at Math.SE.  That's amazing!  I'm wondering if this is the current per-site record.

**Question**: Is 7 Socratic badges the current per-site record?

Comment: Re *"...learn a substantial amount"*: But even after more 1,000 questions apparently not learning [community norms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and still using Stack Overflow [as a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). A more notorious one produced nearly 2,000 low-quality questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Even more difficult with the [unmoderated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179) [serial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356964/178179) [downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269392/178179) and the [automated question deletion when score = 0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179). Not mentioning the many [unfriendly comments](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/449/164) that questions receive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The current record is [11 by @uhoh on Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/badges/94/socratic?userid=12102), followed by [10 by @Charo on Italian Language](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/socratic?userid=707). I have a SEDE query for network-wide badge statistics which I [modified slightly](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1604707/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide-sorted-by-total?badgename=Socratic) to answer both @EvanCarroll's question in the comments (that's [@FranckDernoncourt](https://stackexchange.com/users/169656/franck-dernoncourt) with 19 of them) and yours:

[image]