What can I do if originally accepted and upvoted answers suddenly got a large number of downvotes?
The last two weeks saw an exceptionally (and to some extent, abnormally, since I'm new to SO and don't have much posts) large number of downvotes to my answers. Most of those answers originally got at least 1 or 2 upvotes (again, I'm new to SO, so 1 or 2 upvotes matter a lot to me), and some are accepted. However, in the last two weeks many of those upvoted and accepted answer continuously got downvotes for no apparent reason, around 1 month after I posted them. What's more, none of them got any comments suggesting for improvement. Is there anything I can do about this? As I see it, there's a possibility that someone (for some reason) had a grudge against me and continuously downvoted my answers while evading the voting fraud automatic detector mechanism (probably by downvoting one of my answers one day at a time, thus not detectable. The possibility of this is quite high, since the pattern matches exactly that). My current count is around 20 downvotes and thus 40 reputation lost. Is there anything I can do about this? Can I report an anomaly and let the staff or moderators take some actions (voting reversal, for example)? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

There is an automatic system that detects and reverses such votes: see What is serial voting and how does it affect me?. You do not need to take any action unless 24 hours have passed since the votes.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for finding that post, but after reviewing it (I read very fast, so trust me, I actually did read it), your answer was very informative and good. However, the situation I'm facing is that my answers suddenly got continuous downvotes after being posted for around 1 month, but I get one or two downvotes every day instead of a lot in one day. I don't think any moderators will notice it, either. Also, it spans multiple posts, so I can't just flag one of them. Thanks for the help, BTW.

The same thing applies: if the script missed serial votes, flag one of your posts for moderator attention. The moderator flag system doesn't require mods to only take action on the one post - they can look at your entire profile in response to just one flag.

Be careful when you complain about not getting comments when you receive a downvote. See Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received? to understand that sentiment.

Are you sure all answers are worthy of upvotes? I hand checked a few and this one looks like a guess, not an actual answer. The observation done in that answer could as well have been a comment under the question.  Voters are picky on that and for good reasons. It reduces noise for future visitors.

As this seem to be only related to SO, consider posting on their Meta: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

@rene Per the serial voting FAQ (the duplicate target), voting fraud inquiries should not be posted on per-site metas. Said text was added into the FAQ by a Stack Overflow moderator.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I would argue this question shouldn't be about serial voting, but fine.

Looking at your SO profile, some user is serial downvoting you and they are doing it slowly to avoid triggering the serial voting reversal script.
The solution is: be more proactive when a user continuously downvotes another user, because the current serial voting reversal script is only triggered if a user cast 3 downvotes or more in a day. It totally misses the serial votes that are more spread over time.

Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped. But what is the most effective way of being " more proactive"?

@LukeL being "more proactive" is the solution from the SE platform side. From the SE user side, we can only contact mods for the particular voting issues, and  bug SE employees to try to convince them to make SE less toxic by improving their serial detection script.

So in my case is there anything I can do?

@LukeL flagging one of your questions that got serial downvoted.

Mods can't see who voted but employees can - so yeah, flag one of your posts, let them know your concerns and let them escalate it

You absolutely cannot tell by looking at the profile (or the screenshot you showed) that someone is serially downvoting this person. There is no evidence of this, whatsoever. Your answer is simply wrong. In fact, it's worse than wrong, because it's authoritative-sounding unwarranted speculation.

How do you tell if it's the same user downvoting your posts? You can guess especially if there's been some kind of diatribe in the past but that's not proof. I can disagree  with multiple answers posted by the same user, and downvote the most egregious that doesn't make me a serial downvoter.

"because the current serial voting reversal script is only triggered if a user cast 3 downvotes or more in a day" Is this (officially) public knowledge? I feel like this shouldn't be shouted from the rooftops.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's a web-crawling bot that's downvoting, intended to damage SO's reputation (eg. from a competing QA site).  There are a number of people who's Q's got serial downvotes in the same minute: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356964/are-moderators-allowed-by-the-stack-exchange-anti-serial-downvote-script-to-seri ,

@Demis Yeah that was me who received these downvotes :( In that case, the voter was a mod.

Oh! That question got downvoted to -17, which means at least 17 different people, so not a bot then! Looking at your Q's, I think you're getting downvoted for the unusual way in which you're asking and then answering your own questions - asking a question like "how can I...", then answering "no you can't". It may look to that Mod like you're gaming an easy way to get Rep.  I see you're probably just posting your thought process "live" to SE hoping it helps others. These questions seem too trivial, especially if the answer is just "no". A misunderstanding methinks - on the mod and your parts

@Demis "These questions seem too trivial". How do you determine when a question is too trivial?

One way is from the fact that they get downvoted, another is to compare to questions that get upvoted. There’s not any hard rule about this, it’s determined by random internet people’s whims (the wisdom of the masses) - so Don’t take it personally!

i do see that it took you some ~4hrs to find the answer yourself, so they're seemingly non-trivial. Maybe wait a day before posting the question - if you've found the answer then no need to post. but if by the end of day two you're still scratching your head, then post the question.

@Demis "i do see that it took you some ~4hrs to find the answer yourself". 100% incorrect. Here are the 4 questions: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136637/18147;
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86482/18147; https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109782/18147; https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136776/18147 . None of them took me some ~4hrs to find the answer. Instead, I typically add the answer at least a few months later. "Don’t take it personally" never said I did.

True, sorry I misread that.
