# Allow OP to ping closevoters in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close, notifications

Before a question is closed, the OP didn't know which users cast closevotes, unless they have left a comment. However, sometimes the OP would like to discuss about the closevote(s) with the closevoters. Feature request: Allow OP to ping closevoters in comments. E.g. `@closevoters blah blah`.

For example, if the closevote was "unclear" but the OP doesn't see what is unclear, then the OP could ping the closevoters to ask what should be clarify.

Comment: The current function of this is by design. Single vote closers can be pinged (gold badge or mods) but a post closed with multiple votes does not allow pinging. Also, users with too little reputation can not easily see who voted to close. Can you discuss why the current function should be changed and how you would avoid the concerns that caused this to be the status quo?

Comment: @Catija Motivation: avoiding 1 misinformed close vote to snowball into closing the question. What are the concerns that caused this to be the status quo? The main issue I see with the feature request is in the case where they are multiple voters with different close reasons. Unsure how to handle that.

Comment: Part of any FR is doing the research to understand why things are the way they are. Research this here on MSE and then edit your post. Please don't rely on content in the comments to make your case.

Comment: Close voters are already "pinged", often by means of revenge voting.

Comment: If the closevoters are going to say what they see the problem as, they'll already do so. Hassling them is just going to create ill will and arguments.

Comment: @rene  [Be more proactive when a user continuously downvotes another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179)

Comment: Op can start a meta or chat discussion. The problem is that these questions are typically unwelcomed on the meta sites.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica can't start chat since close voters are anonymous till the question gets closed. If asking on meta, people would typically comment that the question isn't closed yet.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, but might attract others with reopen vote capability. Or might get tips to attract others. Of course it is far from the effectivity if he could ping the close voters directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: 1) close voters are already pinged 2) the current function of this is by design, so why change it?

> - Close voters are already "pinged", often by means of revenge voting. – [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) [Jan 4 at 7:50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359132/allow-op-to-ping-closevoters-in-comments#comment1198884_359132)

> - If the closevoters are going to say what they see the problem as, they'll already do so. Hassling them is just going to create ill will and arguments. – [Nij](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/341260/nij) [Jan 4 at 8:20](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359132/allow-op-to-ping-closevoters-in-comments#comment1198895_359132)

> - The current function of this is by design. Single vote closers can be pinged (gold badge or mods) but a post closed with multiple votes does not allow pinging. Also, users with too little reputation can not easily see who voted to close. Can you discuss why the current function should be changed and how you would avoid the concerns that caused this to be the status quo? – [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)**[♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)** [Jan 3 at 22:48](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359132/allow-op-to-ping-closevoters-in-comments#comment1198866_359132)

> - Part of any FR is doing the research to understand why things are the way they are. Research this here on MSE and then edit your post. Please don't rely on content in the comments to make your case. – [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)**[♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)** [Jan 3 at 22:54](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359132/allow-op-to-ping-closevoters-in-comments#comment1198868_359132)

I disagree, but the large ratio of downvotes:upvotes (20:6 currently) seems to indicate I'm in the minority.

Comment: I totally agree with you, not only from the OP's protective, but also as a close voter. If I make a mistake i'd like people to be able to ping me in order to correct/not repeat the same error.